# RANKX not working when data summarized in power pivot table

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap, powerpivot, dax

I am trying to rank records in power pivot table using DAX as below in MSSQL analysis service tabular model.

Example details:

I have a shop sales detail in table.
e.g.

```
ShopNo date sales
-----------------
1 2014-11-09 120
1 2014-11-09 130
2 2014-11-10 130
2 2014-11-10 135
```

In pivot table data is analyzed month and year wise.

I want to see result like

```
ShopNo sales rank
-----------------
2 265 1
3 250 2
```

Any solution is there to display statewise population automatically.

Thanks

Comment: can you share some sample data so that I can do some powerpivot trial-and-error magic :-)

Comment: @PetrHavlík Thanks for reply. I have changed dummy example by real need. Please write if want more info.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve the ranking quite easily with PowerPivot using this formula:

```
RankShop:=RANKX(ALL(SalesTable[ShopNo]), [Sum of sales],,,Dense)
```

With *SalesTable* being your shops sales table. If you then create a pivot table - drag ShopNo onto Rows and add new *Measure* (Excel 2010, in 2013 it's *Calculated Field*). The resulting table could then look like this:

[image]

To find out more about RANK function, I suggest [this article](http://ayadshammout.com/2013/02/19/dax-rankx-function-scenarios/).

In order to hide the rank value in Grand Total row, add a simple condition that puts blank values in case of grandtotals:

```
=IF(HASONEVALUE(SalesTable[ShopNo]), [RankShop], BLANK())
```

Hope this helps.